# Spring Boot: How to retrieve the username by user_id?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I have already connected my springboot to MySQL database. I want to display the username when `user_id` is specified in the HTTP request. e.g. `http://8080/user/1` must display the name of the user with `user_id` 1.

The table contains attributes as:

```
| Integer user_id; | String username; | String fathername; | String mothername;
```

I have already tried this code in by Controller class but i does not seem to be working

```
     @RequestMapping("/{userid}")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getById(Integer userid) {
    String name="";
    try {
   Optional<Persondetails> persondetails=persondetailsRepository.findById(personid);
      name = String.valueOf(userdetails.getName());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      return "Name not found";
    }
    return "The Name of the user is : " + name;
  }
```

my repository code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
public interface UserdetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<Userdetails, Integer> {
public Optional<Userdetails> findById(Integer userid);
}
```

**It says `getName()` is undefined for the type Optional**

But i have defined it in Userdetails class

```
public class Userdetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="user_id")
private Integer userid;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
@Column (name="fathers_name")
private String fathersname;
@Column(name="mothers_name")
private String mothersname;
    public Userdetails() {  
}
public Integer getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setname(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getFathersname() {
    return fathersname;
}

public void setFathersname(String fathersname) {
    this.fathersname = fathersname;
}

public void setMothersname(String mothersname) {
    this.mothersname = mothersname;
}
public String getMothersname() {
    return mothersname;
}
}
```

Comment: `http://8080/user/1 ` is not valid URL

Comment: Yeah i gave it as an example . 1 indicating the user_id

Comment: To answer your question would require a lot of work. Could you please include the work you have already done? If you haven't done anything, I would recommend that you start with something small and work iteratively as there are so many layers to this question.

Comment: You need to pass host,port and  context of your application.                                                          Ex http://localhost:8080/demo-user/users/1

Answer (score 0):

It's missing the method type GET, you can do by two options:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public User findOne(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return userService.findById(id);
 }
```

OR

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String getString(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    return "Helloworld";
}
```

Spring boot Connect with Mysql and get Data.

application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/demo-user
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

*Controller.Java

```
@RequestMapping({"/users"})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
    public User findOne(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return userService.findById(id);
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {
    User findById(int id);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public User findById(int id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

UserRepository .java

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Integer> {
    User findOne(int id);
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private String email;

   //setter and getter
}
```

Make request from browser or application.

http://localhost:8080/demo-user/users/1

Comment: What is the problem?